# Wrapping all Standard and Custom Jackson Deserializers within a Universal Property Deserializer

Tags: java, jackson, kotlin, json-deserialization

I'm using Jackson 2.8 and looking to wrap all standard/custom deserializers in a standard wrapping deserialize in order to do some post processing on each deserialized value instance of every property. To accomplish this, I subclassed a `BeanDeserializerModifier` in order to pass the base `JsonDeserializer` and the appropriate `JavaType` for the given property type to a subclass of `StdJsonDeserializer` which then calls that base deserializer and performs various operations on the resulting value instance.

During deserialization I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.lindisfarne.MundaneDataClass: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

Without the `BeanDeserializerModifier`, the operation would, of course, work just fine -so clearly I am getting an incorrect or incomplete deserializer. How can I get the correct deserializer for the given type?

Full Kotlin code to reproduce issue below:

```
package com.lindisfarne

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue


class ReferencingBeanModifier() : BeanDeserializerModifier() {

    override fun modifyDeserializer(config: DeserializationConfig?, beanDesc: BeanDescription?, deserializer: JsonDeserializer<*>?): JsonDeserializer<*> {

        val javaType = beanDesc?.type
        return WrappingDeserializer(deserializer = deserializer, javaType = javaType)

    }

}

class WrappingDeserializer(val deserializer :JsonDeserializer<*>?, val javaType: JavaType?) : StdDeserializer<Any>(javaType) {

    override fun deserialize(jsonParser: JsonParser?, deserializationContext: DeserializationContext?): Any? {

        val instance = deserializer?.deserialize(jsonParser,deserializationContext)
        println(instance)

        //do more stuff

        return instance
    }


}

data class MundaneDataClass(
        val trivialBoolean: Boolean = true,
        val borningInt:Int = 1,
        val meaninglessString:String = "yes"
)

fun massiveFailure() : Unit {

    val mapper = ObjectMapper()

    with (mapper) {
        registerModules(
                KotlinModule().setDeserializerModifier(ReferencingBeanModifier())
        )
        disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
    }

    val mdc = MundaneDataClass()
    val dataJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(mdc)
    val mdc2 = mapper.readValue<MundaneDataClass>(dataJson)

}
```